# Is there a way to have Ant create a shell or batch runtime script?

Tags: java, ant, shell

Is there a way to have Ant create a runtime shell or batch runtime script instead of having to manually create the script myself.

It would be similar to the functionality of [link text](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipsessgen/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it can be done.  Here's a simple example (your link is not working right now ... sourceforge error thrown).  The basic idea is to write the file using the [echo](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/echo.html) task, then run it using the [exec](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) task:

```
<property name="myls" value="myls.sh" />
<echo file="${myls}">
ls
</echo>
<exec executable="sh">
    <arg value="${myls}"/>
</exec>
```

When run gives the following, as the working directory only contains the build file and the script:

```
Buildfile: build.xml
     [exec] build.xml
     [exec] myls.sh
```

This is of course unix-specific, but you could do similar equally well on other systems - for windows you'd change the executable to `cmd` I believe.  You can take this further and pass arguments to your new script too if needed. For example:

```
<property name="myls" value="myls.sh" />
<echo file="${myls}">
ls $@
</echo>
<exec executable="sh">
    <arg value="${myls}"/>
    <arg value="b*"/>
</exec>
```

When run now only sees the build file:

```
Buildfile: build.xml
     [exec] build.xml
```