# How to automatically create batch / shell scripts to run a Java console application?

Tags: java, ant, maven, batch-file, sh

I have a Java command-line application, and would like to create an Ant* build script that will create all the required batch/shell scripts to run the application successfully including all the classpath variables. I need it to do the following:

1. Create a shell script file for Linux/Unix and a batch file for Windows/DOS
2. Add all classpath dependencies (from Maven or simply use the build path in Eclipse)
3. Add any necessary boilerplate sh/bat code to run (ENV variables, JAVA_HOME, etc.)

I found only a partial answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3927975/6042824).

But I haven't found anything that does this basic and trivial task that every build involves.

**Disclaimer** - the original question was Ant/Maven, but I would prefer to see if it can be done in Ant.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Maven the best solution for this is the [maven-appassembler-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/) which handles the creation of a shell script / batch file. In combination with maven-assembly you can create a tar.gz or zip archive which contains everything which is needed.

Comment: Thank You! Is there such a thing for Ant?

Comment: This works really well - also puts all dependencies in a location that the script references

Comment: This seems to only allow you to specify the main class and not a jar file that already has a manfiest that specifies the main class.

Answer (score 3):

Maven knows the [`dependency:build-classpath`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/build-classpath-mojo.html) goal, which does most of the dirty work:

```
mvn dependency:build-classpath -DoutputFile=cp.txt
```

You can use this generated file in a shell script to create the java classpath (I know, it ain't much, but it'll get you started).

Or you can use the [exec-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html) to launch a main class from the current maven context. Something like this will do:

```
mvn compile org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2:java \
    -Dexec.mainClass=com.yourcompany.YourClass
```

Comment: Thanks, is there an ANT solution? The best will be to use Eclipse classpath, but I have a feeling the industry / community is indeed leaning toward Maven, mayve I should as well... How about Gradle?

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use a binary executable builder for Java applications. Some of these can be launched from ant with provided ant tasks.

For example, [exe4j](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/exe4j/overview.html) can create executables for command-line applications, and supports Windows, Linux and Mac. The executable wraps the Java code, its classpath, and JVM search path. A custom ant task "com.exe4j.Exe4JTask" supports generation of the executable from an exe4J configuration -- which can be created with a friendly wizard.

Comment: This is a great option. But I would like to keep it script based

Answer (score 1):

[Apache commons Launcher](http://commons.apache.org/launcher/example.html) creates startup scripts for you. Both Windows and Linux script will be generated. Also it can be integrated with Ant.

I hope it will help others.