# Maven: lifecycle phase to run a program?

Tags: java, maven

I can use Maven to compile and test a program

```
mvn compile
mvn test
```

Is there a lifecycle command to simply run the program, or generate a script which will run the program?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? Running a program which does what? Code generation? Preprocessing of resources? A bit more detail, please ;)

Comment: script generation & packaging http://stackoverflow.com/a/5262214

Comment: Whatever it is the IDE's do when the run button is clicked.  For example, a hello world would print "Hello World". :)

Comment: how do you build a JAR with the mvn command?  deploy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are asking this question, it means it's unclear to you what the [Maven lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) really is.

There is no lifecycle *command*, only a build lifecycle, which is made up of different *phases*.

So to make it clear: there is a build lifecycle, which is made up of phases, which are made up of plugin goals.

When you are invoking Maven with

```
mvn compile
```

You are invoking a build *phase*. In Maven, there is a [list of predefined ordered phases](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference). When you invoke a phase, all of the phase before it are also invoked. Invoking a phase means that you are invoking all of the plugins that are bound to this phase. For the `compile` case, this means it will, among others, invoke the `maven-compiler-plugin` wich is bound to the `compile` phase by default.

So to answer your question strictly: no, there is no lifecycle command to do that.

However, you can configure a plugin in your POM, which will be bound to a certain phase, and invoke that phase. For that, you can refer to @manouti's answer which introduces the `exec-maven-plugin`.

Comment: Indeed, I was quite unclear.  The list of phases has cleared things up a lot regarding the build cycle.

Answer (score 6):

There is no lifecycle phase to do this but you can bind the `exec-maven-plugin`, specifically the [`exec:java` goal](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html) to it. For example, to run the goal on the package phase:

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
     <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>1.4</version>
     <executions>
         <execution>
            <id>run-java</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
         </execution>
      </executions>
      <configuration>
           <mainClass>main.Class</mainClass>
      </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: But this is not a lifecycle command, per se (simply because there is really no such thing as a lifecycle command).

Comment: @Tunaki You're right. I adapted my answer accordingly.