# A .bat skeleton to start Java programs

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

Has anyone ever published a nice Windows .bat skeleton script to initialize simple Java applications? I'm looking for a skeleton that would help me to set a default JAVA_HOME in case a JAVA_HOME does not exists, CLASSPATH, JVM initialization arguments, application arguments, handle with weird characters passed as arguments, etc.

Linux distributions offer an example initialization script in /etc/init.d/skeleton which are very handy to create your own init scripts if you need them. I'm looking for something similar to start simple Java applications in Windows.

Comment: How do you want to input the name and arguments?

Comment: In windows it's as easy as `set "path=your_directory"`

Comment: @Hackerdarshi I'm not sure what "name" you're talking about. I'm thinking of something very simple, to overwrite by hand the arguments in this skeleton/template file.

Comment: name means the name of the class / jar file

Comment: @Norsk It is problably simple, yes. Anyway, I'm looking for a skeleton to do that in a more "standardized" way, dealing with issues related to weird Windows paths. I see that Java application servers usually have a huge .bat script file associated to properly configure the server when someone starts it. I guess that there might be lessons learned that could be brought to this skeleton file, and I'd love to take advantage of those lessons.

Comment: @Hackerdarshi Right. I'm thinking about manually overwriting the name of the class/jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better solution here: [How to automatically create batch / shell scripts to run a Java console application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261316/how-to-automatically-create-batch-shell-scripts-to-run-a-java-console-applicat)

It is a maven plugin that generates Linux and Windows shell scripts that works pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

This is something I use, since I have an extensive set of utilities written in Java that are managed by a batch server (Tivoli).

I have one file that exists in each environment (TEST, STAGE, PROD), and the individual batch files will call the first file if the environment variables aren't set.

```
:: dbUtils_env.cmd
::
:: This file is used to define the dbUtils environment variables
::  Author: MLS
::
::  History:
::
::  MLS 06/06/2011  Genesis.

::@echo off

:: The dbUtils_env valid values are TEST, STAGE, PROD

set dbUtils_env=TEST
set dbUtils_home=C:\dbUtils
set context_table=%dbUtils_home%\dat\context.dat
set oracle_home=C:\app\myuser\product\11.2.0\client_1
set java_home=c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre

:end
```

Each Calling batch script (located in the same directory) will call this if it doesn't find the appropriate environment variable.

```
:: dbImport.cmd
::
:: This file is used to execute the dbImport java program
::
::  Author: MLS
::
::  History:
::
::  MLS 06/06/2011  Genesis.
::

@echo off

set ctxId=%1%
set tmplName=%2%

if "%ctxId%" == "" goto usage
if "%tmplName%" == "" goto usage

if NOT DEFINED dbUtils_home call %~dp0%dbUtils_env.cmd
if NOT DEFINED context_table call %~dp0%dbUtils_env.cmd

:: Check to see if setup was successful

if NOT DEFINED dbUtils_home goto envExit
if NOT DEFINED context_table goto envExit

set dbimport_jar=%dbUtils_home%\bin\dbImport.jar
set opencsv_jar=%dbUtils_home%\bin\opencsv-2.3.jar
set mssql_jar="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Drivers\sqljdbc_3.0\enu\sqljdbc4.jar"
set ora_jar=C:\app\myuser\product\11.2.0\client_1\ojdbc6.jar
set db2_jar="C:\Program Files\IBM JDBC Driver\jdbc_sqlj\db2jcc4.jar"
set java_switches=

java %java_switches% -cp %dbimport_jar%;%opencsv_jar%;%ora_jar%;%mssql_jar%;%db2_jar% com.myplace.dbimport.DBImport %*

if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 goto errorExit

goto end

:envExit

echo Call to dbUtils_env.cmd failed, exiting...
exit /b 1

:usage

echo.
echo Usage: dbImport.cmd ^<Context ID^> ^<Template Name^> [-procParam=\proc1,...,procN\"]
echo          ex. ^>dbImport dbCtx myTemplate
echo.
exit /b 1

:errorExit
echo.
echo dbImport exited with an error, aborting...
echo. 
exit /b 1

:end
exit /b 0
```

The one nice thing about doing it this way, is that I can setup properties files that include the dbutils_env, so I can setup one properties file that works across all my environments:

```
TEST.MAIL.server=mycompany.smtp
TEST.MAIL.sender=TheBatchScheduler@mycompany.com
TEST.IMPORT.filename=%dbUtils_home%\\import\\SomeTestFile.txt

STAGE.MAIL.server=mycompany.smtp
STAGE.MAIL.sender=TheBatchScheduler@mycompany.com
STAGE.IMPORT.filename=%dbUtils_home%\\import\\SomeStageFile.txt

PROD.MAIL.server=mycompany.smtp
PROD.MAIL.sender=TheBatchScheduler@mycompany.com
PROD.IMPORT.filename=%dbUtils_home%\\import\\MyProdFile.txt
```