# Plugins to create .sh from .jar for maven projects?

Tags: maven

As like "install4j" plugin is used to generate ".exe executable", is there any plugin to generate ".sh executable" for Linux/Unix OS platforms?

Or can we use same "install4j" plugin to generate ".sh executable"?

Comment: You can take a look at [appassembler-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have gone through your link as well as this http://www.mojohaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/usage-program-scripts.html

Comment: As of now, I haven't found the exact solution to create the ".sh executable" from the plugin, rather we have to create "zip" which contains "sh executable" & "jar" by using "maven-assembly-plugin".
Also, follow the [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261316/how-to-automatically-create-batch-shell-scripts-to-run-a-java-console-applicat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if we have any maven plugin for creating .sh from Java jar.
But you can try below work around .

## install the git bash on your local machine i.e build machine.

## use maven exec plugin to invoke a main class in your project pom.

## in main class you can can use Java process runtime to execute the .sh command and script using git bash.

## now your script and command will be as below link.

https://coderwall.com/p/ssuaxa/how-to-make-a-jar-file-linux-executable
Note: if you are using Linux system to build your project then no need of git bash. You can directly invoke this commands from your main call.

Comment: Thanks for the reply buddy, followed steps mentioned by you & it works for me.