# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonProcessingException

Tags: java, spring, maven, noclassdeffounderror

Can someone help me with this? I am doing a Spring framework TwitterCLI java project and having issues when I try to run it. I am not sure if I ran it correctly, I searched online which states that `NoClassDefFoundError` only happens when you leave out a dependency.  However I am pretty sure I have the correct `jackson-core` dependency in my POM file.

The errors shown:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonProcessingException
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:650)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:632)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        ... 7 more
```

My pom file dependencies:

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.28</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--oauth 1.0 and httpclient4-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>oauth.signpost</groupId>
      <artifactId>signpost-commonshttp4</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--Jackson JSON-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
      <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--testing-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--spring-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

I tried

```
mvn clean compile package
```

which built successfully, but after I tried to run

```
java -classpath target/test-classes ca.jrvs.apps.twitter.TwitterCLIApp post "hahaha" "42.98693964646016:-81.31011004242582"
```

it gave me the above error for

```
<jackson.version>2.14.0</jackson.version>
```

I also tried versions 2.7.3, 2.12.0 or 2.14.0, didn't work for all.

I might run the app in a wrong way so I run the app as suggested:
`mvn spring-boot:run`, but now it gave me the error for my main class:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ca.jrvs.apps.twitter.TwitterCLIApp
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:418)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:553)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:750)
```

Comment: What is the parent tag of `dependencies`?

Comment: its as below: ```<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
  </parent>```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the problems are with the way that you are running the command:

```
java -classpath target/test-classes ca.jrvs.apps.twitter.TwitterCLIApp \
    post "hahaha" "42.98693964646016:-81.31011004242582"
```

First of all, the `target/test-classes` subtree will contain only classes in your project's `test/java` tree.  Your application classes will be in the `target/classes` subtree .

Second, the `target` tree doesn't include the dependency JARs.

So when you run the command like that, you don't have any of your dependencies ... or even the application itself ... on the *runtime* classpath.

---

So what is the correct way to deal with this?

It depends what you are trying to do.

- If you simply want to run the tests:

  ```
  mvn test
  ```
- If you want run the application via one of the `main` entry-point methods:

  ```
  mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=<class-fqn> -Dexec.args="arg1 arg2 arg3"
  ```
- For a spring-boot application, it is even simpler:

  ```
  mvn spring-boot:run
  ```
- If you would prefer to run the application *without* using `mvn` as a (umm) launcher you could:

  1. Generate the a classpath file with:

     ```
      mvn dependency:build-classpath -DoutputFile=cp.txt
     ```

     as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/5261456/139985 to create a file containing the classpath.  Then user the file like this:

     ```
     java -classpath @cp.txt <class-fqn> <arg> ...
     ```
  2. Use [`appassembler-maven-plugin`](http://www.mojohaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/) or similar to generate a launcher shell script.
- For spring-boot, I understand that `mvn` can build an executable JAR file for the project which contains all of the dependencies.  You can run that JAR file like this:

  ```
   java -jar my-project.jar <arg> ...
  ```

Comment: I actually skip all Junit and mock unit tests, am I able to skip tests in a spring boot project? And after I tried to run `mvn spring-boot:run`, it shows the error that `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ca.jrvs.apps.twitter.TwitterCLIApp` and build fail...